# Compare insert data to existing data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

The title might be misleading, I just can't wrap my head around this.

I have 3 tables; Employee, EmployeeSchedule and LocalStore. In the Employee table there is a column of data type bit called "IsManager", in EmployeeSchedule the days are simply labeled "Monday" to "Sunday" and each store has a unique StoreID:
[image]

The rule I want to implement is the following:

*A store cannot have have more than 1 manager per day.*

If I try to add another manager to that store on the same day, I want the table to throw a error message.

I am thinking of something like this, how can I check that a manager is not already assigned to that store at the same day?

```
USE [StoreSystem]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[CheckManagerAndDay]    Script Date: 2020-12-14 10:56:28 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[CheckManagerAndDay]
     ON [dbo].[EmployeeSchedule]
     AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
 AS
 BEGIN
     SET NOCOUNT ON;

     IF EXISTS (
         SELECT *
         FROM EmployeeSchedule
         JOIN Employee ON Employee.ID = EmployeeID
         JOIN LocalStore ON LocalStore.ID = StoreID
         WHERE IsManager = 1 and StoreID = ?? and Day = ??
     )
     BEGIN
         THROW 50000, 'Cannot have more than one manager on the same day.', 1;
     END
 END
```

Comment: What's the context in which you were thinking of running the code you're showing us? Ad-hoc SQL? Stored Procedure? Trigger? Might be clearer (assuming not ad-hoc) if you can show us more of that context.

Comment: Trigger unless another way is more recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find this a bit painful to implement in SQL Server.  Why?  Because SQL Server triggers are *set based*.  They are intended handle multiple rows.  That means that duplicates can appear in two different ways:

- There is an existing manager in the store and the new data inserts a second one.
- There are no existing managers but the new data has two.

Ouch.

There is an alternative way -- that doesn't use triggers.  But there is a complication.  The `isManager` flag is redundantly stored in `EmployeeSchedule`.  Then we use a foreign key to be sure it is correct and an unique index for the property you want:

```
alter table Employee add constraint unq_isManager_id
    unique (isManager, Id);

alter table EmployeeSchedule add constraint fk_employeeschedule_isManager_EmployeeId
    foreign key (isManager, EmployeeId) references Employee(isManager, EmployeeId);
```

And then the unique constraint that does what you want:

```
create unique index unq_employeeschedule_day_manager
    on employeeschedule(day)
    where isManager = 1;
```

Voila!  No triggers!

You should also fix your data model so `day` is stored as a `date` rather than a string.  Storing date/time values is strings is a really bad habit to get into.

Comment: Although if `Day` is the day of the week (narrative suggests so) an integer coding may be more appropriate than an arbitrary `date`.